# Не удаётся загрузить файлы на хостинг

Tags: php, сервер, права, ftp-сервер

Возникла проблема - я делаю проект, на котором реализовал загрузку на сервер картинок. Делаю это с помощью следующего PHP-кода:

```
$image_name = stripslashes($_FILES['upload'.$i]['name']);
$newname = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/school-hub/img-lib/".$image_name;
$copied = copy($_FILES['upload'.$i]['tmp_name'], $newname);
```

На локальном сервере всё работает идеально, но как только я заливаю проект на хостинг, меня благополучно посылают сообщением об ошибке:

```
Warning: copy(/home/vhosts/school-hub.coolpage.biz/school-hub/img-lib/image.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/vhosts/school-hub.coolpage.biz/school-hub/savetask.php on line 19
```

Насколько я понял, хостинг не разрешает мне загружать на него файлы. Возможно ли как-нибудь обойти это ограничение или реализовать загрузку по-другому? Может быть можно как-то выдать права доступа? Я с хостингами на "Вы", так что жду помощи.

Всем заранее спасибо!

Comment: смотрите кто владелец этого каталога и какие права. Владелец должен быть www-data (для апача) и права на запись\чтение

Comment: @ArchDemon ftp у меня net2ftp. Там такой функционал, что мне аж плохо стало... И всё, что я могу там делать - это загружать и удалять файлы... Прошу прощения за тупость, но где это можно посмотреть?

Comment: Это не ответ, поэтому напишу в комментарий... Это очень хорошо, что хостинг не разрешил записывать файлы таким образом, т.к. это прямой путь к взлому вашего сайта. Любой может загрузить file.php вместо картинки и потом выполнить его на сервере просто открыв в браузере school-hub.coolpage.biz/school-hub/img-lib/file.php . Надо обязательно проверять тип файла и удалять все не-цифробуквенные символы из $image_name прежде чем использовать эту переменную в пути к файлу.

Comment: @astax все проверки есть. Всё, что не картинка и больше 5 мегабайт даже не рассматривается...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если есть доступ по ssh, то установить права на папку для картинок - `chmod 777 school-hub/img-lib`. Если нет ssh, то можно попробовать сделать то же самое через FTP клиент. Вот, [пример](https://www.hostinger.ru/rukovodstva/kak-izmenit-prava-dostupa-k-faylam) (найден в гугле наугад).

Если нет ssh доступа и нет возможности установить владельца и права на папку, то остаётся только загружать картинки по ftp прямо из php.

Т.е. вместо `copy` использовать `ftp_put`, предварительно установов соединение. См. тут - https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php

Comment: Я Вас обожаю <3